# R installation on server and Visualizing the plots or graphs.

Tags: r, amazon-ec2, data-visualization

I want to install R on the AMZ EC2 servers. This is my first time I am doing so. 
I have been using R installed on my Laptop but to process large data-set my Laptop gives up! I will be using the Visualization capabilities for graphs and Plots. I was looking for solution that will help me to Visualize the Plots on the server without using the X11 or port forwarding from my local machine when I remotely login to the servers.

Thanks for your responses....

Comment: You can probably use RStudio: http://www.r-bloggers.com/rstudio-in-the-cloud-for-dummies/

Answer (score 2):

While you won't be able to visualize the plots using X11, you should still be able to create PDFs:

```
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(1:20)
dev.off()
```

You can then download and view those PDFs.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend [RStudio Server](http://rstudio.org/docs/server/getting_started) that allows running full-featured [RStudio IDE](http://rstudio.org/screenshots/) from a browser on your local machine/laptop. I've been using it with EC2 and it has been great - no need to save/transfer those pesky pdf files every time one needs to look at a plot..